# How to reassign disk to file system?

Tags: mount, disk

I'm mess my mounting of the directory with device:

```
lorancechen@schan:~$ sudo df -hl
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       790M  9.0M  781M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/schan--vg-root  226G  6.6G  208G   4% /
tmpfs                       3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                   473M  463M     0 100% /boot
/dev/sda1                   511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                       100K     0  100K   0% /run/lxcfs/controllers
tmpfs                       790M     0  790M   0% /run/user/1000
/home/lorancechen/.Private  226G  6.6G  208G   4% /home/lorancechen
```

Obviously, 226G for a home user.I'm not sure what's the means of `/home/lorancechen/.Private`?

Besides, `sudo fdisk -l` showing Linux LVM use 237.5G:

```
lorancechen@schan:/boot/grub$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B9F1D7BF-5BE5-4457-8589-B7BA73C5298E

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 500117503 498067456 237.5G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/schan--vg-root: 229.6 GiB, 246503440384 bytes, 481452032 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/schan--vg-swap_1: 7.9 GiB, 8489271296 bytes, 16580608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 7.9 GiB, 8488747008 bytes, 16579584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I'm sure my file system has some problem and now I can't use `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` install anything because of

```
cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic' to  
'/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic.dpkg-new':   
failed to write (No space left on device)
```

What's the problem of the disk assign? how can I reassign the disk?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need `sudo` for `df`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/home/lorancechen/.Private` looks like file encryption to me. Have a look at the output of

```
cat /proc/mounts | grep lorancechen
```

Your problem with `apt-get` is due to the fact that your `/boot` partition is full. Some Linux distros do not delete old kernels. So you have to install some script for that or do it manually from time to time. Go to `/boot` and delete some of the old kernels and initrds.

Comment: thanks, solve with `sudo apt-get autoremove`.